# How can I access request parameters from dispatchLoopShutdown in Zend (PHP)?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a series of functions being called inside the dispatchLoopShutdown function. Right now I have to change the body of the response based on the request made (in this case, depending on the URL).

How can I access attributes such as the URL inside the dispatchLoopShutdown so I can change the body of the request the way I want depending on what the client requested? I'm a PHP/Zend beginner.

Comment: can you use $this->event->getRouteMatch() ? Some code would help.

Comment: Is this really ZF2? I am removing the tag now, as dispatchLoopShutdown() is a zf1 feature.

Comment: It is ZF1. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved it by simply accessing $this->getRequest();